# Creating and exporting/importing variable with awk?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, gawk

I have a file where every line is a new customers information, such as

```
Pop corn, pop@gmail.com, 50, 200
```

I am currently trying to see if it is possible to use a `awk/gawk script` to assign each column to a variable and then pipe those variables to `sed` to be substituted into a template? I would be running both awk/gawk and sed from within a bash script. What is a good implementation I could follow to get this done? I'm trying not to use `grep`, because I'm trying to learn how to cohesively use awk/gawk, sed, and bash scripts together or `perl` since I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: Do you want to assign each column to a shell variable or to an `awk` variable?

Comment: I thought I would go ahead at first at use `awk` variables if it was possible (which I now know is), if it were not then I would have tried using variables declared with in the bash script and exporting them to `awk`.

Comment: Depending on the specifics, it may be that you don't need `sed`, or that you don't need the shell variable to do your templating, or even `awk`. Since you only give minimal info about what it is you _actually_ want to do ("substitute (something) into a template"), it's difficult to give a "good implementation" for anything other than the parsing of the file that you talk about at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you should be better off doing something like:

```
while IFS=, read -r name email x y _ignored_; do
  email=${email# } x=${x# } y=${y# }
  sendmail -oem -oi -t << EOF
To: $name <$email>
Subject: Whatever

x=$x y=$y
EOF
done < file.csv
```

That, is since you're going to run at least one command per line anyway, use the shell to read the lines into variables. And use shell variable expansion in the here-document instead of `sed` to do the template expansion.

`awk` wouldn't help much here as while it can run commands with its `system()` or `getline()` (but via running a shell to parse a command line), it cannot *set* environment variables for those, other than building the shell code that sets those variables. So, it would become quite convoluted and less efficient. Something like:

```
CODE='sendmail -oem -oi -t << EOF
to: $name <$email>
Subject: Whatever

x=$x y=$y
EOF' awk -F ', *' -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  {system("name="shquote($1)" email="shquote($2)" x="shquote($3) \
          " y="shquote($4)"\n"ENVIRON["CODE"])}' < file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function of `awk` to read the line into the array with specific delimiter.

```
awk '{split($0, array, /,/)}' customers_file
```

Then you can pass to `sed` what elements of this array you want to feed it with just printing those elements within `awk`.

Comment: is this pearl? or is `split` also an implementation in bash/awk?

Comment: Hi, this is `awk` and `split` is its built in function.